# investment (trading) oursourcing

Tags: investing, trading, hedge-funds

Where can I outsource my investment or trading? I'm asking this question because it takes time from me and I can use my time better in my own field. I know there are some things like mutual funds, but I want more profit. Trading stocks/crypto/... is more profitable than mutual fund.

What is the minimul amount of money they accept to be invested?

Is hedge fund a good option? How much is their annual return usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hedge fund is for accredited investors only.

Some futures brokers offer automatic-trading software that they are familiar-with. Or managed-futures can be found.

But I would recommend closed-end-funds. A CEF is a mutual fund that trades on the stock market and then doesn't make redemptions. Since the CEF doesn't make redemptions then it can use leverage and hedging which are often less liquid positions and of course more aggressive investing. There is a cefconnect website source.

Or If the investor's interests were known then there are small partnerships available that don't require accredited investors.